# Calculating the limit over $\partial \Delta ^2$

Tags: simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

Suppose we have the diagram of spectra $$A \to B \to C$$
Then taking the limit of this diagram is essentially taking the limit over the Nerve of the category $$\cdot \to \cdot \to \cdot$$
which I believe is exactly $\Delta^2$.

$\Delta^2$ has a subcomplex $i:\partial \Delta ^2 \hookrightarrow \Delta^2 $. So given this functor from $\Delta^2$ to Spectra, we can compose with the inclusion $i$ and get a functor from $\partial \Delta ^2$ to Spectra. My question is, What is the limit of this functor over $\partial \Delta ^2$? In particular I would like to be able calculate the homotopy groups of this limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit over $∂Δ^2$ is simply the homotopy equalizer (alias ∞-equalizer)
of the maps given by the image $f\colon A→C$ of 0→2 respectively the composition of the images of 0→1→2.
Up to homotopy, the latter composition can be taken to be $f$.
Thus, we are interested in the homotopy equalizer of $f$ and $f$.

This homotopy equalizer can be computed as the homotopy fiber of the map $$A⨯C=A⊕C→C⨯C=C⊕C$$
whose component $A→C⨯C$ is the map $(f,f)\colon A→C⨯C$, whereas the component $C→C⨯C$ is the diagonal map.

The homotopy groups of this homotopy fiber can be computed in the standard manner, for example, using the long exact sequence associated to this fiber sequence.